# The underline of entry cannot removed

Tags: xamarin.forms

I want to make a entry that without underline. I tried two solutions but both can not work well.

```
Control.Background = null;
```

it is not go well and I take another solution:

```
GradientDrawable gd = new GradientDrawable();
            gd.SetColor(global::Android.Graphics.Color.Transparent);
            Control.SetBackground(gd);
            this.Control.SetRawInputType(Android.Text.InputTypes.TextFlagNoSuggestions);
            Control.SetHintTextColor(ColorStateList.ValueOf(global::Android.Graphics.Color.White));
```

It also not go well in android but work well in ios.I do not understand why.

Comment: https://dzone.com/articles/xamarinforms-borderless-entry-using-custom-rendere if only people use google before dumping their questions!

Comment: Hi @Ali123 I cannot open google you know.besides the solution of the article is not work I have tried before ask.

Comment: Are you using custom renderers ?

Comment: @Batuhan Hi I find where is the error.

Comment: What do you mean you can't open google? If you can't open google, how do you expect to authenticate against it?

Comment: Also, why are you trying to recreate the library instead of trying to resolve the issue in the library which is working for most poeple

Comment: I have tried many issues in the library and not work for me so I create the new library but I find the problem of my program.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try add xml styling named `editText_bg.xml`,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <solid android:color="#FFFFFF" />
    <stroke
        android:width="1dp"
        android:color="#2f6699" />
    <corners 
        android:radius="10dp"            
        />
</shape>
```

And you can give this to entry as background resource :

```
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(CustomEntry), typeof(AndroidCustomEntryRenderer))]
namespace XXX.Droid.Renderer
{
    public class AndroidCustomEntryRenderer : EntryRenderer
    {
        public AndroidCustomEntryRenderer(Context context) : base(context)
        {
        }
        protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Entry> e)
        {
            base.OnElementChanged(e);

            if (Control != null)
            {
                Control.SetBackgroundColor(global::Android.Graphics.Color.White);
                Control.SetBackgroundResource(Resource.Drawable.edittext_bg);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It can be fix your issue.

Answer (score 0):

Try my implementation(working for Android and ios). PlainEntry is empty class inherited from Xamarin.Forms.Entry

Android

```
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(PlainEntry), typeof(PlainEntryRenderer))]
namespace UR.Droid.Renderers
{
    public class PlainEntryRenderer : EntryRenderer
    {
        public PlainEntryRenderer(Context context) : base(context)
        {
        }

        protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Entry> e)
        {
            base.OnElementChanged(e);

            if (Control != null)
            {
                this.Control.
                    SetBackgroundColor(global::Android.Graphics.Color.Transparent);
                Control.SetPadding(0, 0, 0, 0);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

iOS

```
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(PlainEntry), typeof(PlainEntryRenderer))]
namespace UR.iOS.Renderer
{
    class PlainEntryRenderer: EntryRenderer
    {
        protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Entry> e)
        {
            base.OnElementChanged(e);

            if (Control != null)
            {
                Control.BorderStyle = UITextBorderStyle.None;
                Control.BackgroundColor = UIColor.FromRGBA(0, 0, 0, 0);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

If you want to use renderers for all Xamarin.Forms.Entry like  not the  than specify:

```
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(Xamarin.Forms.Entry), typeof(PlainEntryRenderer))]
```